# Visual Studio, repetead references between projects load only for some projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded a solution from a mercurial repository, when loading it some GAC references load only for some projects but not for all.

All projects are targeting .net 4.5.1 and all references look the same in the the csproj files. This is happening in visual studio 2015, for some reason using vs2013 loads even less references(I get more errors when compiling).

Any ideas of what could be going on? I'm thinking of formatting my laptop but would like to try something else first.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by removing one of the affected projects from the solution and re-adding it. After doing that all other references with errors fixed themselves like magic. Don't know if it is a bug with windows 10, .net, or what. :S